# Spring Validation: get single (relevent) validation message for multiple constraints

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I have multiple constraints applied on a single field **name** like:

```
@NotNull
@Min(value=3, message="Name should be atleast 3 chars long")
@Max(value=40, message="Name can not be longer than 40 chars")
@Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]+", message="Name can only contain letters")
String name;
```

For a value of **"af3"** of that field, I am getting all the above 4 messages. I want to display only the relevent ones which apply. i.e, in this case, message should be "Name can only contain letters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Max` and `@Min` are for numbers only, that's why you get those messages. According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Max.html) (similar text for [min](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Min.html)):

> The annotated element must be a number whose value must be lower or equal to the specified maximum.
>
> Supported types are:
>
> BigDecimal
>      BigInteger
>      byte, short, int, long, and their respective wrappers

[`@Size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) (and max/min) can be used for validating String length, similarly
`@Length` (from hibernate validators) and max/min parameters is used to validate length of a String.